# Is there a way to connect to a git remote located on the onion hidden service?

Tags: onion-services, help, server, git

I have recently set up an onion hidden service specifically to use it with git. I've used the method described in the answer for [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hidden-git-service) question, however, I wasn't able to figure out the exact way to connect to the server, since neither ssh, nor git seem to support onion link format. Is there a way to connect to the git remote over tor?

*Note:*
Onion service itself is functional. Tor Browser has no issues connecting to the server. However, git and ssh return errors like:

`bash: ssh://git.<myhiddenservice>.onion/git/: No such file or directory`

or

`fatal: repository 'git.<myhiddenservice>.onion/git/<myproject>.git' does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[torsocks](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/torsocks) is the way to go. You may need to install it separately from Tor if it is not installed automatically.

- Make sure Tor is running: `systemctl status tor`
- Run your command through torsocks: `torsock git pull` or `torsocks ssh abcxyz.onion`

Another option is to run `torsocks --shell`. This will make all commands in that shell automatically run through Tor. This will end if you exit from the shell or close the terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

While marked answer is 100% correct I use a bit different approach. For ssh connections using OpenSSH client I utilze ProxyCommand for *.onion sites in the following way:

```
Host *.onion
        ProxyCommand                    socat STDIO SOCKS4A:<tor socks hostname or IP>:%h:%p,socksport=9050
```

This should also be the only change needed for git ssh connections.

In a way it may or may not be a good thing: while using torsocks will force ALL connections (ie. to submodules) to go through TOR network, using proxy command above will only route hidden services through TOR. Please evaluate the risk before going this route.

Comment: hey Tomek years has passed but your solution is still working , thanks a lot!